# Setup Windows and Linux, dual boot and a storage folder that can be written and read by both

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have just setup Windows 8 + Ubuntu 14.04 on dual boot on my laptop. Now I'd like to have a common storage "partition" where I store personal documents, movies, music, etc that can be read and written to by windows and ubuntu.

Doing some research, I came across [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/) which basically tells you to create a NTFS partition for storage, then edit the fstab file in Ubuntu and edit Libraries in Windows. That sounds cool because I don't have to install any third party for this but the little problem I see with this article is that it's really old, written in 2010, so I'm thinking if something has changed and there's better, more recommended ways to do that nowadays in 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still set it up like the article suggests in 14.04, the permissions have to be set correctly in both OS's.

One very easy way to handle this is to use the GUI in 14.04 and create a folder in the Desktop directory of your Windows partition.

Mine is located on WinPartition:/users/mylogin/desktop.
It is easy, if you have the space on your windows install.

Optionally, pick a neutral partition, set up the folder from Ubuntu, open all permissions and then create a shortcut to the folder in Windows.